# Docker - Configuring PhpMyAdmin container behind Apache reverse proxy container

Tags: apache, docker, phpmyadmin, docker-compose, reverse-proxy

I want to setup a configuration of docker containers on my AWS EC2 host.

I wish to have a Apache reverse proxy container which takes in requests from EC2 host on ports 80, 443, and 8080 and passes it on to containers behind it. Requests on 80 & 443 should be passed to a web-application container (with exposed port 80). Whereas those on 8080, should be passed to a container running phpmyadmin (with exposed port 80). I'm using the official **phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin** docker image.

Currently trying to run this setup for local development, where:

- I'm unable to open phpmyadmin on http://localhost:8080/
- However, I'm able to successfully open the web-application on http://localhost/

*Inspecting the request in Chrome Dev Tools, shows the 'Status' of the phpmyadmin request as 'failed'. I am unable to figure out what is causing the request to fail. 
Would appreciate any help on this.*

Below is my configuration.

**Environment Variables (.dev.env):**

```
# For PHPMyAdmin
PMA_HOST=db
PMA_PORT=3306
PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI=http://localhost:8080/
```

**docker-compose.yml configuration:**

```
# Development
version: '3'

services:
  db:<test_database_config>

  proxy:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.proxy.dev
    env_file: .dev.env
    volumes:
      - ./etc/apache2/sites-available:/etc/apache2/sites-available
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links:
      - db
    env_file: .dev.env
    expose:
      - '80'
    depends_on:
      - db
      - proxy


  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    env_file: .dev.env
    volumes:
      - ./website_content:/var/www/html/website_content
      - ./subdomain_website_content:/var/www/html/subdomain_website_content
      - ./etc/apache2/sites-available:/etc/apache2/sites-available
    extra_hosts:
      - "subdomain.localhost:127.0.0.1"
    expose:
      - "80"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - proxy
      - phpmyadmin
```

**Reverse-proxy Apache configuration (enabled config in sites-enabled):**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/proxy_port_80_error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/proxy_port_80_access.log combined

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://web:80/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://web:80/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/proxy_port_443_error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/proxy_port_443_access.log combined

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://web:80/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://web:80/
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/proxy_port_8080_error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/proxy_port_8080_access.log combined

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://phpmyadmin:80/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://phpmyadmin:80/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Have you checked where you have your ec2 port 8080 and 443  are open in security group?

Comment: Actually, that would be for production, where yes, the ports are open. Currently I'm trying to run this setup locally for my development environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was nothing major. It turned out that my reverse-proxy Apache wasn't configured to listen on port 8080.

Added the same to my **ports.conf** file:

```
Listen 80
Listen 8080

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

There was **no issue with the docker-compose.yml & environment variables config**; they worked as it is.

---

Also for anyone using the apache configuration above, here's another small change - only the VirtualHost for port 443 need be inside the IfModule, like given below:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  #ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  #DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/proxy_port_443_error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/proxy_port_443_access.log combined

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://web:80/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://web:80/
</VirtualHost>

</IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  #ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  #DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/DNZProject/
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/proxy_port_80_error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/proxy_port_80_access.log combined

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://web:80/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://web:80/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
  #ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  #DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/DNZProject/
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/proxy_port_8080_error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/proxy_port_8080_access.log combined

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://phpmyadmin:80/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://phpmyadmin:80/
</VirtualHost>
```